# .eslintcache в vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

создаю проекта с помощью CRA, и потом после первого save в корне появляется файл .eslintcache. Пользуюсь vscode. Как это убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот файл создается с помощью react-scripts 4.0.1. Если изменить версию на 4.0.0, то эта проблема исчезает. Я думаю, в будущем это будет изменено.